# Tracking what happens to files on a network share

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Is there some kind of software out there that can monitor a file share on a network and record who (computer/user or application) deletes or modifies files - as we are having issues with data going missing from a particular location.

I know this sounds a bit like I'm after a bit of FBI like software, but I just thought someone more knowledgeable than me may know what I am looking for or at least dispel my ideas that software like this is, is not even possible! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Windows' built-in auditing features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.03.auditing.aspx). Note that enabling auditing for filesystem objects would create a large amount of logs in most setups. You would either need a tool to handle that or sufficient expertise in scripting to craft such a tool on demand.

See the [documentation on auditing](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/325.advanced-security-auditing-in-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by using [File Auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)